# Cordova application to reload image (SVG)

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, svg

I am working with cordova android application, I want to reload an SVG image automatically while other activity of that app unaffected. I have tried this code but it is not refreshing. Please direct me for this.

This is the image source I want to refresh automatically say after 1 second

```
<img src="https://api-m2x.att.com/v1/charts/f9dfbcdeebe88fb1c3899716ae6949ae.svg?width=600&height=450">
```

This is the code I am trying with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Accelerometer Graph</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://api-m2x.att.com/v1/charts/f9dfbcdeebe88fb1c3899716ae6949ae.svg?width=600&height=450">
  <script>
  setInterval(function() {
      var images = document.images;
      for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
          images[i].src = images[i].src.replace(/\btime=[^&]*/, 'time=' + new Date().getTime());
      }
  }, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 seconds
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest

Comment: It looks ok - although I'd get the Image element a different way. When you test with remote debugging, what do you see in the console? Do you see an error? Did you try adding a console.log to ensure your setInterval is really running.

Comment: I didn't add consol, I tried in app, and It was not refreshing the SVG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see it. Your code to update the image based on time fails to change because your original URL doesn't include time=. Therefore the replace does nothing, and the URL doesn't change.

Comment: As a quick fix, I added &time=1 to the URL and it helped. But note that running it every 1000 second is too quick. The image never finishes downloading.

Comment: I tried with 10 seconds, still not working. Not sure why it is not changing :(

Comment: When I tested on the Desktop (you aren't really doing anything that needs Cordova), I can confirm it made a network request every N seconds. Are you sure the image is supposed to change? I just tested the image and it looks similar to what I saw this morning. I've reloaded a few times too.

Comment: The image will not change now, because I stopped data stream, so data points are not changing.Hence you didn't get anything . But when I was changing I couldn't see change. And cordova has nothing to do with SVG image, but I have to do in cordova platform.

Comment: Well can you turn the stream back on? :) I'm pretty sure my change was good. Here is my entire test script. ANd you can run this on your desktop. There is no need to use Cordova to run this. https://gist.github.com/cfjedimaster/b1f5f4c80811b59778c5

Comment: There is no need of cordova for that but my application is on android cordova and that code and my other activity code is on cordova, hence it is necessary to be in cordova.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding me. Your issue is a code one - not one related to Cordova. You are not using anything that requires you to *test* on Cordova. You can test w/ a normal desktop web browser and THEN send it to Cordova when done. Does that make sense now?

Comment: How is it not working? Do you see the network requests in console? Again, if you can turn on the 'data' thing so the data really changes, I can test locally too.

Comment: Yes working now, as per your suggestion I just did `&time=1000` as 1000 millisecond = 1 second. Although I need to check this in my phone. Will let you know final result. As of now GET call is working :)

Comment: It is working fine in my app too. Thanks buddy for your sincere help. Carry on helping :)